# How to add a certain number to an object's coordinates

Tags: animation, game-engine, coordinates

I'm currently making a first person game in BGE. I animated an action for the camera of slowly going up and down to make the walking more realistic. I added it to the player's logic, but instead of moving forward, the player moves a small distance from the spawn point, and then immediately goes back.

I thought that maybe this happened because I added a keyframe for all the axes, and I could just add a keyframe for the Z axis. But then I thought that this could malfunction if I was on a different height level, because it would just bring me back to the original level.

So a way to do this would be to just add a number to the coordinates of the player, but I couldn't find anything on how to do that, and don't even know if it's possible.

How will I add a number to coordinates, no matter what they are, and how do I make it a keyframe?

.blend file:

[image]

Comment: Why not just add `+1` behind the value? Inserting a Keyframe can be done by hovering over and pressing `I`.

Comment: @quiliup would you mind writing an answer with instructions?

Comment: @quiliup I added my file to the post, maybe you can take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you for the file. Unfortunaltely I cannot detect any problem you mentioned ("moving forward, the player moves a small distance from the spawn point, but then immediately goes back"). You also declared you "animated an action for the camera", but I could not find a single keyframe in your whole scene.

Comment: @quiliup I made a mistake and uploaded a file without the actions. I will try again and let you know when I put when I put it on my post.

Comment: @quiliup Alright, I put the file on the post.